# How to properly access javascript object properties via this in the following example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop

I want to create the following JavaScript object:

```
function Thumbnail(thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.width = 200;
    this.height = 150;
    this.element = init(this.width, this.height, this.thumbnailUrl);
    this.element.addEventListener("mouseover",this.onmouseover);

    function init(width, height, thumbnailUrl) {
        var thumbViewHTML  = "<div class='container shadow' style='width:"+width+"px; height:"+height+"px; background: green;'>";
        thumbViewHTML += "<div class='container' style='width:100%; height:80%; background: yellow'>";
        thumbViewHTML += "<img class='centered' src='"+thumbnailUrl+"'  style = 'max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;'/>";
        thumbViewHTML += "</div>";
        thumbViewHTML += "<div class='container' style='width: 100%; height:20%; background: black'>";
        thumbViewHTML += "<div class='textStyle centeredVertically' style='margin-left:5px; color: white'>Landscape</div>";
        thumbViewHTML += "</div>";
        thumbViewHTML += "</div>";

        return DOMElementFromHtml(thumbViewHTML);
    }

    return this;
}

Thumbnail.prototype.onmouseover = function() {
    console.log(this.width); //undefined with this pointing to this.element property on the Thumbnail object
}

function DOMElementFromHtml(htmlString) {
    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
    return tempDiv.firstChild;
}
```

When I access `this.width` on the `onmouseover` handler I get *undefined* because this points to the `this.element` member of the `Thumbnail` object. Is there any way to get `this` inside that method to point to the `Thumbnail` instance instead of the `this.element` instance.

I assume I could implement `onmouseover` in the local scope of the `Thumbnail` constructor and that might work but what if I want `onmouseover` to be a public method that can be modified externally?

Comment: Did you call ```new Thumbnail()``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the function to `this` like so:

```
this.element.addEventListener("mouseover",this.onmouseover.bind(this));
```

Although you had `this.onmouseover`, as you don't call it right there, but (need to) pass a function reference, the actual call (when the event triggers) is not made with the `this.` prefix, and so it will be called without a specific context. Depending on whether you are in non-strict or strict mode, `this` will then refer to the global object or be `undefined`.

This behaviour you can override with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), which creates a new function, but which will be ensured to have as context the argument you pass to it.

You can read more about the subject at ["How does the `this` keyword work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Great that does work, thanks. I am a pretty experienced OOP dev but JavaScript is a different kind of beast in that regard :).

Comment: Yes, it is confusing. Some have suggested to program without the `this` keyword as it regularly leads to undesired "surprises", while others embrace it.